# Assigning parameter to a variable in gradle

Tags: gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I am just trying to assign the value from the parameter I pass to a gradle task. For example I run this task
gradlew assembleTestApp -PtestParam=testVarible

in my build.gradle i want to assign the value to a variable

def var = $testParam

above is not working.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Gradle uses the `$` only to ineterpolate variable values inside a string. To use a parameter as a regular variable, you do not need the $sign.

```
def var = testParam
println "var: " + var + " testParam: " + testParam
println "var: $var testParam: $testParam"
```

results in:

```
gradle -q -PtestParam=foo
  var: foo testParam: foo
  var: foo testParam: foo
```